# Want to know a request is served by which dyno at heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku

I have a sinatra app deployed at heroku, and I have scaled web worked to 3 dynos, so requests are being served by 
web.1
web.2 and 
web.3 respoectively.
I want to know in ruby, from within a conroller action that current request is being served by which dyno and then want to keep this in database. I did a bit of google but not found any satisfactory answer.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I have built a long polled app, to support a publisher / subscriber pattern. so if a subscriber is long polling at one dyno, and publisher published content on the same dyno, then I can push that content to the subscriber, otherwise I have to use some other means. So for the former purpose I need to know this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to identify a heroku dyno number from within the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465234/how-to-identify-a-heroku-dyno-number-from-within-the-app)

Answer (score 0):

There is really no way to know this. You don't get any HTTP headers from Heroku that specify which Dyno is handling the request, so there's no way to tell. The best you can do is have Heroku stream all your logs somewhere ([syslog drain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#syslog-drains)) so that you can parse the logfiles and match request URIs to Dynos.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a very hacky way to do this on boot with a worker process.

1. You need to be able to monitor the output from `heroku logs --tail`, see https://github.com/dblock/heroku-commander for an example. The worker reads logs.
2. The worker makes an HTTP request to the app, eg. GET app/dyno?id=uuid1. The response is the MAC address of the dyno that responded, eg. mac1.
3. The worker can see in the logs that uuid1 went to web.5, which responded with its mac. Bingo, the worker now knows.
4. PUT app/dyno?mac1=web.5&mac2=web.6, etc. Each dyno that receives this will compare its mac to one of the macs and respond true/false that it now knows who it is.
5. Repeat until the worker has reached all dynos and all dynos know.
6. Watch for dyno restarts periodically.

You got to wonder though why you need to know that you're "web.1". Why can't it be a unique UUID, like the MAC address of the machine?