# How to identify a heroku dyno number from within the app?

Tags: heroku

Is there a way to identify the heroku dyno name (e.g. web.1, web.2) from within the application?  I'd like to be able to generate a unique request id (e.g. to track requests between web and worker dynos for consolidated logging of the entire request stack) and it seems to me that the dyno identifier would make a decent starting point.

If this can't be done, does anyone have a fallback recommendation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked this question of Heroku support, and since there are others here who have asked similar questions to mine I figured I should share it.  Heroku staff member JD replied with the following:

> No, it's not possible to see this information from inside the dyno.
>   We've reviewed this feature request before and have chosen not to
>   implement it, as this would introduce a Heroku-specific variable which
>   we aim to avoid in our stack. As such, we don't have plans to
>   implement this feature.
>
> You can generate / add to your environment a unique identifier (e.g. a
>   UUID) on dyno boot to accomplish a similar result, and you can
>   correlate this to your app's dynos by printing it to your logs at that
>   time. If you ever need to find it later, you can check your logs for
>   that line (of course, you'll need to drain your logs using Papertrail,
>   Loggly, etc, or to your own server).

Unfortunately for my scenario, a UUID is too long (if I wanted such a large piece of data, I would just use a UUID to track things in the first place).  But it's still good to have an official answer.

Comment: Pfft, this is unacceptable since I capture metrics and my dashboard can't be reconfigured every time the source (UUID) changes. I'll raise the request again :-)

Comment: We eventually discovered [snowflake](https://github.com/twitter/snowflake) and then heroku's own [noeqd](https://github.com/noeq) id generation server.

It's a pity that heroku doesn't expose their noeq service to their customer base, but it's very easy to get it up and running, and each server is easily capable of generating over a million unique ID values per second, which is more than enough for tracking request IDs.

Comment: This is outdated, there is a $DYNO environment variable now according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/16381078

Answer (score 20):

Recently that issue has been addressed by Heroku team.

The Dyno Manager adds `DYNO` environment variables that holds identifier of your dyno e.g. `web.1`, `web.2`, `foo.1` etc. However, the variable is still experimental and subject to change or removal.

I needed that value (actually instance index like 1, 2 etc) to initialize flake id generator at instance startup and this variable was working perfectly fine for me.

You can read more about the variables on [Local environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#local-environment-variables).

Comment: Where does foreman get the info? When I run a rails app locally with a Procfile and foreman, the logs have "web.1", "worker.1" etc. in them.

Comment: Ah, foreman run locally sets $PS, which $DYNO replaced on heroku.

Answer (score 3):

Heroku has a [$DYNO environment variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#local-environment-variables), however there are some big caveats attached to it:

1. "The $DYNO variable is experimental and subject to change or removal." So they may take it away at any point.
2. "$DYNO is not guaranteed to be unique within an app." This is the more problematic one, especially if you're looking to implement something like Snowflake IDs.

For the problem you're attempting to solve, the [router request ID](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-request-id) may be more appropriate. Heroku passes a unique ID to every web request via the X-Request-ID header. You can pass that to the worker and have both the web and worker instance log the request ID anytime they log information for a particular request/bit of work. That will allow you to correlate incidents in the logs.

Answer (score 3):

This may not exactly answer the question, but you could have a different line in your Procfile for each worker process (using a ps:scale of 1 for each). You could then pass in the worker number as an environment variable from the Procfile.

Two lines from an example procfile might look like:

```
worker_1: env WORKER_NUMBER=1 node worker
worker_2: env WORKER_NUMBER=2 node worker
```

Comment: This is a great idea, I also added a `HOST_TYPE` so all of the same types could identify themselves, eg `HOST_TYPE=worker`

Answer (score 1):

The foreman package which `heroku local` uses seems to have changed the ENV variable name again (heroku/7.54.0). You can now get the worker name via `$FOREMAN_WORKER_NAME` when running locally. It has the same value `$DYNO` will have when running on Heroku (`web.1`, `web.2`, etc)

Answer (score 0):

The `foreman` gem still uses `$PS`, so to access the dyno name and have it work both on heroku and in development (when using `foreman`) you can check `$PS` first and then `$DYNO`. To handle the case of a local console, check for `Rails.console`

```
dyno_name = ENV['PS'] || ENV['DYNO'] || (defined?(Rails::Console) ? "console" : "")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's dangerous to use the DYNO environment variable because its value is not guaranteed to be unique. That means you can have two dynos running at the same time that briefly have the same DYNO variable value. The safe way to do this is to enable dyno metadata and then use the HEROKU_DYNO_ID environment variable. That will better let you generate unique request ids.  See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata

Comment: How can one determine the host type from its ID? eg `1vac4117-c29f-4312-521e-ba4d8638c1ac` means nothing!