# Can you programmatically access current Heroku dyno id/name?

Tags: java, heroku

On Heroku, can you programmatically, from within an app, get some kind of identifier for the dyno currently executing your code? For example the dyno name (e.g. "web.1" or "worker.1"), or some other id.

If yes, how to do this in Java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is always the hostname of the machine (which looks something like `d.LONG_GUID`. I suppose (though haven't tried) that this should work:

`String localhostname = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();`

Also, a little known secret, but you can get the "web.1", "web.2" id's by looking at the value of the environment variable `PS1`

`String hostId = System.getenv("PS1")`

**EDIT** 2013-July-26

As per [Heroku changelog](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/293), the local environment variable `DYNO` now replaces `PS`, which replaced `PS1`.

Comment: Good tip! I think you mean "PS" (not "PS1", which is the prompt).

Comment: Thanks. Upvote then :-) I actually do mean PS1, unless they've changed it in the mean time.

Comment: Yep, I did upvote. :) I can confirm that the dyno name is definitely in "PS", and not in "PS1".

Comment: Worth noting that the env variable is "**experimental and can be changed or removed at any time**" (as stated in the changelog). But this does answer my question, thanks!

Comment: Similarly, is there a variable or an other way to retrieve, inside the application, the number of running dyno's?

Comment: @AurélienOoms this deserves a separate question I guess. Anyway it looks like https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno-list or https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#formation-list might do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku team have addressed that issue and now the Dyno Manager adds `DYNO` environment variables that holds identifier of your Dyno e.g. `web.1`, `web.2`, `foo.1` etc. However, the variable is still **experimental and subject to change or removal**.

You can get value of that variable using `System.getenv(String)` in Java.

Example:

```
final String dynoId = System.getenv("DYNO");
final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\.(\\d+)").matcher(dynoId);

String id = null;

if(matcher.find()) {
    id = matcher.group(2); // returns index: 1
    // matcher.group(1) - returns name: web
}
```

I hope that will help